# Ayuda al introducir un Array como clave y un ArrayList como valor HashMap

Tags: java

Estoy intentando que en el HashMap , la clave, de tipo String, representa el nombre del tema, el cual se extrae del array “temas”, accediendo con el código del tema, el cual se encuentra en el fichero.

En resumidas cuentas por poner un ejemplo, lo que quiero es que en el HM se introduzcan dentro de la clave(PROGRAMACIÓN), solo los libros cuyo tema sea "PROGRAMACIÓN", y en la clave (SISTEMAS Y REDES) pues que solo se introduzcan los cuales su tema sea "SISTEMAS Y REDES".

Para esto se me ha ocurrido desarrollar un método que me recoja el fichero libros.txt, y que este me lo añada en un ArrayList, y luego añadir la llamada de este metodo que me devuelve el ArrayList en el método del HashMap, **pero con lo que tengo echo lo unico que consigo es que que en cada clave del HasMap me meta la todo el ArrayList y no solo los que tienen un tema en concreto.**

Clase EXAMEN:

```
public class Examen {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    Examen e = new Examen();

    e.crearListaLibro("ficheros/libros.txt");
    String[] temas = {"PROGRAMACION", "DISEÑO WEB", "SISTEMAS Y REDES","OFIMATICA"};
    e.ejercicio1(temas);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



public ArrayList<Libro> crearListaLibro(String rutaFichero){

    try {
        ArrayList<Libro> listaLibros = new ArrayList<Libro>();
        BufferedReader fichero = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rutaFichero));
        String registro;
        Libro libros=null;
        while((registro=fichero.readLine())!=null) {
            String[]campos = registro.split("#");
            libros=new Libro(Integer.parseInt(campos[0]), campos[1], campos[2], 
                    Float.parseFloat(campos[3]), campos[4], LocalDate.parse(campos[5]));
            listaLibros.add(libros);
        }
        fichero.close();
        System.out.println("Fin de la lectura del Fichero!!");
        return listaLibros;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public HashMap <String, ArrayList<Libro>> ejercicio1(String [] temas){
    HashMap <String, ArrayList<Libro>> mapaLibros = new HashMap <String, ArrayList<Libro>>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < temas.length; i++) {
        mapaLibros.put(temas[i], crearListaLibro("ficheros/libros.txt"));
    }
    return mapaLibros;
}
```

Clase Libro:

```
public class Libro {
private int id;
private String tema;
private String titulo;
private float precio;
private String portada;
private LocalDate fecha;

public Libro(int id, String tema, String titulo, float precio, String portada, LocalDate fecha) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.tema = tema;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.portada = portada;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTema() {
    return tema;
}

public void setTema(String tema) {
    this.tema = tema;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
public float getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
public void setPrecio(float precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}
public String getPortada() {
    return portada;
}
public void setPortada(String portada) {
    this.portada = portada;
}
public LocalDate getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
public void setFecha(LocalDate fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}
```

}

Fichero libro.txt esta colocado en el orden de id, tema, titulo, precio, portada y fecha :

```
0#PROGRAMACION#INTRODUCCION A  ANSI SQL#7.77#portada.jpg#2015-09-07
1#OFIMATICA#ACCESS 2000#33.21#1.jpg#2010-05-19
2#PROGRAMACION#ACTIONSCRIPT3 PARA FLASH CS3#12.75#2.jpg#2009-02-16
3##HTML5 y CSS3#24.35#3.jpg#2013-05-29
4##MODELOS ECONOMICOS Y FINANCIEROS CON EXCEL 2007#21.5#4.jpg#2014-12-19
5#OFIMATICA#WORD 2000#14.75#5.jpg#2011-08-10
6#SISTEMAS Y REDES#RED HAT LINUX FEDORA#14.78#7.jpg#2017-05-30
7#PROGRAMACION#VISUAL BASIC .NET#18.42#6.jpg#2011-05-07
8#PROGRAMACION#LENGUAJE ENSAMBLADOR DE LOS 80X86#38.25#8.jpg#2003-05-29
9#PROGRAMACION#VISUAL .NET 2005#12.45#9.jpg#2011-10-19
10#PROGRAMACION#DELPHI 7#24.5#10.jpg#2014-05-29
11#DISEÑO WEB#FINAL CUT PRO 6#27.45#11.jpg#2012-09-19
12#DISEÑO WEB#PHOTOSHOP CS#17.5#12.jpg#2013-05-29
14#SISTEMAS Y REDES#ENRUTADORES CISCO#19.35#14.jpg#2013-05-19
15#PROGRAMACION#PHP 5#8.45#portada2.jpg#2011-11-11
```

Y GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO !!!

Comment: En ningún momento estas diferenciando por el tema a la hora de leer los datos del fichero. Lectura que por otra parte es muy ineficiente de la forma que la tienes planteado. Leelos primero todos de una sola vez y luego discriminas por tema.

Comment: Gracias, por tu aporte, tomare en cuenta lo de que deberia leerlos todos de una sola vez, pero ademas de eso me gustaria saber de que manera los discriminarias tu por tema, porque la verdad no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Comment: Tu segundo campo  de cada línea es el tema, solo tienes que hacer comparativas sobre los temas definidos e ir trabajando con ellos en el HashMap.